# Show only the user's own account in a table that is editable when logged in, PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem regarding on how can I access a account that is only able to see that currently logged in account, Please help on what Mysql statement should i use thanks :).

So i made a page that checks if the user is admin or customer and its working.(Code below is for login if admin or customer).

Verify if its the admin or customer page.

```
<?php
    include("dbcon.php");
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM admininfo WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' and type='admin'";
    $sql1="SELECT * FROM customerinfo WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' and type1='customer'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $count1 = mysql_num_rows($result1);

    if ($count==1) {
        //ADMIN
        $_SESSION["username"];
        $_SESSION["password"];
        $_SESSION["type"];
        header("location:menu.php");

    } elseif ($count1==1) {
        //CUSTOMER    
        $_SESSION["username"];
        $_SESSION["password"];
        $_SESSION["type1"];
        header("location:menu1.php");
    } else {
        echo "Invalid username or password";
    }
?>

<?PHP
    include('dbcon.php');
?>
```

I also made a page on showing the users info but it shows all the users that are existing, However I want to only show the logged in user only i dont know what mysql statement should I use please help (code below for editing user info P.S. i know its the while loop that has shown all the existing users).

Edit the user's information page.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="edit2.php">
            <table>
                <tr><td>First name:</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Last name:</td><td><input type="text" name="lname"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Address:</td><td><input type="text" name="address"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Contact Number:</td><td><input type="text" name="contactno"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="username"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password"></td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="save"</td></tr>
            </table>
        </form> 
        <table border='1'>
            <?PHP
                $customerquery=mysql_query("select * from customerinfo");
                while($customerrows=mysql_fetch_array($customerquery)){
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>Address</td><td>Contact No</td><td>Username</td><td>Password</td><td>Edit</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?PHP echo $customerrows['id'];?></td>
                <td><?PHP echo $customerrows['fname'];?></td>
                <td><?PHP echo $customerrows['lname'];?></td>
                <td><?PHP echo $customerrows['address'];?></td>
                <td><?PHP echo $customerrows['contactno'];?></td>
                <td><?PHP echo $customerrows['username'];?></td>
                <td><?PHP echo $customerrows['password'];?></td>
                <td><a href="edit2.php<?PHP echo '?id='.$customerrows['id']; ?>">edit</a></td>
            </tr>
            <?PHP } ?>
        </table>
        <a href="login1.php">Logout</a>
    </body>
```

Comment: When the user logs in and you make the query to the database to check if the user is admin or not, you could (on success) save the id of the user on a session. Then on your page you can add the where clause that only selects that id.
Alternatively if you can use your username and password already held in session. You just need to make sure that at least username is always unique.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood well.

You should use   `$customerquery=mysql_query("select * from customerinfo where username =".$_SESSION['username']);`

And my suggestion is not to use `*` for select statement, instead use only columns that you would need. It's better practice.

**EDIT**:
Also, I am not sure that your initiation of session is correct.
You should do it like so:
`$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);`

`$_SESSION["username"] = $row['username'];`

**EDIT2**:  Also, you are missing session_start(); statement at the beginning of the script.

**EDIT3**: Also, as said in one comment. It is good practice to keep ID of table users in session. So instead of keeping only username in session add  $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['id'] and when collecting data about user, just do:  `"select * from customerinfo where id =".$_SESSION['id']`

Comment: Im getting a undefined variable notice how am I going to remove that?